# create singleTon class using std::call_once

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, singleton, std

The following code is an implementation of an alternative singleTon class that uses `std::call_once` in `C++11`. Basically, the variable `static_instance` is declared statically along with `static_flag`, and once calling `getInstance` function which is also static function i create the first and only instance of mySingle using call_once.

I'd be happy to hear for any comments regarding code correctness in terms of thread safety, and whether its behavior differ from the standard c++ implementation of defining static variable inside `getinstance`.

mySingle.h

```
class mySingle
{
    static mySingle *static_instance;
    static std::once_flag static_flag;
public:

    mySingle();
    virtual ~mySingle();
    static mySingle* getInstance();
};
```

mySingle.cpp

```
#include "mySingle.h"

mySingle * mySingle::static_instance;
std::once_flag mySingle::static_flag;

mySingle::mySingle(){}
mySingle::~mySingle(){}

mySingle* mySingle::getInstance()
{
    std::call_once(g_flag, [&]() { static_instance = new mySingle(); });
    return (mySingle*) static_instance;
}
```

Comment: first thought out of head - why would you complicate something that can be as easy as typical static variable singleton?

Comment: the reason is that in windows (at least that's what i've checked), the standard implementation uses access to thread local storage (if you disassemble the compiled code, you see access to register `gs:[58h]` which is TLS. I wish to avoid that.

Comment: See this article : http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-data, and look at scott meyers singleton

Comment: @Gojita, great article, thanks !

Comment: Meta: did you mean `static_flag` rather than `g_flag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [std c++ call_once](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once), it says

> Executes the Callable object f exactly once, even if called concurrently, from several threads.

So one would expect that this is thread safe